# C# inheritance at the constructor using base and MVVM communication

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, mvvm, telerik

I'm building a GUI using Telerik WPF controls based on an SDK example. Note: WPF is new to me and I'm a little rusty when it comes to C#.

**Top level issue:** I'm trying to display a busy indicator using RadBusyIndicator when I load data from a remote database. I know I need to use a background worker for the GUI to remain responsive, but I can handle that once I understand how the communication between objects actually works. The specific line I don't understand is in the `ReportsViewModel` constructor regarding the use of an instance of the `GeotechWindow` in the `base` method.

---

First, the xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="PSE.GeotechLog.WPF.Views.GeotechWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"      
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:PSE.GeotechLog.WPF.Views">

    <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="GeotechBusyIndicator">
        <Grid>
            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GeotechGrid"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReportsToDisplay, Mode=OneWay}">
                <!-- some content -->
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </Grid>
    </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
</Window>
```

---

The code behind the window:

```
namespace PSE.GeotechLog.WPF.Views
{
    public partial class GeotechWindow : Window, IMainView
    {
        public GeotechWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The ViewModel that instantiates my window (somehow - I don't understand the use of the word base or what looks like multiple inheritance between the class definition and constructor):

```
namespace PSE.GeotechLog.WPF.ViewModels
{
    public class ReportsViewModel : ViewModelBase<IMainView>, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly GeotechLogContext context;
        private List<GeotechReport> reportsToDisplay;

        public ReportsViewModel() : base( new GeotechWindow() )
        {
            this.context= new GeotechLogContext();            
            // enable busy indicator
            this.ReportsToDisplay = this.context.GeotechReports.ToList();
            // disable busy indicator
        }
        public List<GeotechReport> ReportsToDisplay
        {
            get { return this.reportsToDisplay; }
            private set
            {
                this.reportsToDisplay = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ReportsToDisplay");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally, the app entry code. Note: I added the newint variable to see how to access something from the ReportsViewModel instance, but I can never seen to access it, which is indicative of the fundamental gap in my understanding.

```
namespace PSE.GeotechLog.WPF
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private ReportsViewModel geotechLogViewModel;
        public int newint;
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            this.geotechLogViewModel = new ReportsViewModel();
            this.geotechLogViewModel.Show();    
        }
    }
}
```

---

**What I don't understand:** How do I use the RadBusyIndicator object `GeotechBusyIndicator` from the `ReportsViewModel` object? As an aside, how do I access `newint` in a derived class? I think this is the same problem, but I could be wrong. I rewrote a lot of code and I've been at this for many days, but the use of inheritance in this situation has me thoroughly confused because of MVVM abstraction techniques. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally you don't talk to the view from the viewmodel directly. The viewmodel just abstracts concepts by exposing properties such as `IsBusy` and the busy indicator binds to the `IsBusy` property on the viewmodel. The `IsBusy` property changes in the viewmodel and the binding system (via `INotifyPropertyChange`) notifies the view that changes have occurred on some bindings. The view updates automatically in response to these notifications. Basically the viewmodel is the logic/data, the view is the visual representation of a viewmodel and the binding system glues the two together

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I've read about MVVM quite a bit and I understand how `INotifyPropertyChange` is supposed to work and I think you're right that it's the answer to my specific issue. I'm still curious how the inheritance works, though.

Comment: I think you are confused about inheritance. c# does not support multiple-inheritance. `ReportViewModel` inherits from `ViewModelBase<T>` and `GeotechWindow` inherits from `Window`. Any other types after the supertype are interfaces and not classes. The class constructor on `ReportsViewModel` is calling the super constructor via the `base` keyword - passing in a new `GeotechWindow` instance (which implements `IMainView`). It's basically just initializing `ViewModelBase<T>` with an instance of the generic type `T` which you've specified as `IMainView`

Comment: `base` always references the current instances super type in the same way that `this` always references the current instance

Comment: Yikes. Okay, I'm definitely missing some critical information about inheritance as you suggested. I will do more reading using the keywords you specified in your comment. I very much appreciate your comments.

Comment: It sounds worse than it is - do you have a background in any other languages? Maybe I can give you the equivalents in C#

Comment: I'm moderately good at C++, Python, and Perl, but I've never used any amount of complex inheritance, which is what I would personally call this since I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Worth looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx - it gives a simple but concise overview of all the features of inheritance. Look at that page and any topics under it on the left hand menu

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This page seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Charleh for the push in the right direction. Because MVVM is so new to me, I didn't even realize it was the obvious way to communicate with the busy indicator.

Adding this to the xaml:

`<telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="GeotechBusyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding Path=GridBusy, Mode=OneWay}">`

and this to the ViewModel:

```
private bool gridBusy;
public bool GridBusy
{
    get { return this.gridBusy; }
    set
    {
        this.gridBusy = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("GridBusy");
    }
}
```

fixed the problem. Now I have to wrap the datacontext load in a background worker and I should be good to go.

Comment: You can use the TPL instead for background thread work (`Task` type and it's derivatives) assuming you are using a later version of .NET (4 onwards) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.100).aspx